# Remove action name as well as parameters in Asp.Net MVC 4 route

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes

This is my action method.

```
public ActionResult Edit(string courseName, int id = 0)
{}
```

Routes defined in config file are

```
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Course",
            url: "{Course}/{Edit}/{courseName}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Course", action = "Edit", courseName = UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Course", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );


    }
```

It is working fine.

My url looks like - /Course/Edit/Androi/1
I want it to look like - /Course/Androi

I dont want to use the Index method and I don't want to show the Id.

Comment: Your route needs to be `url: "Course/{courseName}/{id}"`, (and remove the 1st `UrlParameter.Optional` - only the last parameter can be optional). If you do not show the ID, then your method will never get the ID and it will always be `0`

Comment: routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Course",
                url: "Course/{courseName}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Course", action = "Edit", courseName="", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            ); This is also not working

Comment: Of course it will work (and you do not need `courseName="",`).

Comment: If you enter `.../Course/abc` in you address bar, you will hit `public ActionResult Edit(string courseName, int id = 0)` and the value of `courseName` will be `"abc"`. If its not working for you then you have other code causing the problem.